# FFMPEG performance on remote server

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I am experiencing a completely different performance for FFMPEG on server as compare to development machine. Parameters used are

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00 -to 02:20 -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)' -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts output.mp4
```

**Development Machine Specs**

**MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)**
**Processor** 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
**Memory** 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
**Graphics** Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

**Remote Server Specs**
8 VCPU
32 GB

Does ffmpeg need to have special specs to run on server ?

Same above command can take 15 to 20 minute on server while on development machine it only takes 2 minutes.

Comment: Might be worth looking into whether the commands are being executed on the CPU or GPU

Comment: @FarhadBharucha I confirmed with cloud provider. They didn't have GPU its dedicated server in cloud.